# Appending a table horizontally in div tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

When I click the button, I want append table horizontally instead of vertically

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="javascript" src="emerchemie/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function genTbl(){
    $('#maintd').append('<table width="500" border="1"><tr><td width="300"> Name</td><td width="150">Address</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" onClick="genTbl();" name="e" id="e" value="Submit">
<div style="display:inline" id="maintd"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add style="float:left;" to your table in append method like this:-
$('#maintd').append('<table style="float:left;" width="500" border="1"><tr><td width="300"> Name</td><td width="150">Address</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. 
But when appending the table to the div,  horizontal scroll bar is not on automatically. So tables are appending vertically. 
Please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function genTbl() 

{
    $('#divResults').append('<table style="float:left;" width="500" border="1"><tr><td width="300"> Name</td><td width="150">Address</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>');
}

    </script>
        </head>
    <body>
    <div id="divResults">
    </div>
    <button onclick="genTbl()">submit</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```